# Distributed task scheduling using python on linux

Tags: python, linux, distributed-computing

I have the following scenerio and task:

1. I have access to multiple Machines. I can access all of them via ssh. They are all running linux.
2. I have some arbitrary tasks. For any task, I have a docker image which contains everything to perform that task.
3. I need to run only one kind of task at a time on multiple machines. say I have TaskA and TaskB. Its safe to assume that I shall run only TaskA or TaskB on multiple machines at a time and not simultaneously.
4. Each machine can run the tasks independently. That means, if I am running TaskA on machine1 and machine2, machine1 does not need any result from machine2 and vice versa.
5. I have a large pool of data.
6. Right now, someone manually selects and divides the data and runs the tasks on multiple machines.
7. each task performs computation on the dataset and stores result somewhere.

So here is what I want to do.

1. Lets assume I have some python script or something which is installed in every machine.
2. I initiate a distributed task. May be assign which machines to use and provide the necessary command and parameters to run a particular task.
3. Then I want to divide the data pool into multiple parts and assign each machine to process the data(say data is divided into part1 and part2 and machineA runs part1 and machine2 runs part2).
4. My script monitors the tasks on each machine and assigns tasks accordingly. Say if machineA got some smaller datasets and it finished them quickly, then the scheduler script will assign it new dataset automatically, may be disregarding the previous data division that was done in #3. For example, I had say 10 datasets and initially I assigned 5 tasks to machineA and 5 to machineB. Now machineA finished its tasks quickly and is sitting idle now. the scheduler should then assign the pending tasks of machineB to machineA if necessary.

Please recommend me any tools that can help me do this. if some kind of automation/scripting is needed, I would like to use python/bash or may be C++.

I havent tried anything yet. if Dask or Ray or Apache Spark can help me do these, please provide guidance on how to set things up.

Comment: https://airflow.apache.org/